# Chmod of Symlinked Files

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Recently I tried to access a symlinked file and was received with "Access Denied". So I wanted a way to change all the target files that are symlinked. There is a way to do this in chown (i.e. sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/) but not chmod. Very odd. Does anyone have a better way to do this:

`ls -lR /var/www/ | grep ^l | awk '{print $11, $12, $13, $14}' | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//' | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | xargs -n 1 sudo chmod 775`

- `ls -lR /var/www/` finds all the files in /var/www
- `grep -l` filters out all the symlinked files
- `awk {print $11, $12, $13, $14}` prints all the files including ones with a spaces in them (more spaces include more numbers)
- `sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'` removes the trailing space left over by including spaces in awk
- `sed 's/.*/"&"/'` adds quotes around each file to include files with spaces in their directory
- `xargs -n 1 sudo chmod 775` does the chmod function on all files found

Comment: What is *odd* here?

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: It might be easier to do something like `find /var/www -type l -exec chmod 0775 {} \;` instead

Comment: You want to change the permssions of the link, or the file it points to?

Comment: If the former, see this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12769/symbolic-link-permissions-dont-change-with-chmod

Comment: @cnamejj That will not do anything as symlinks always have the permissions 777. The target of the symlink is not affected my chmod.

Comment: @beepbeep on the Ubunutu system I just tested "chmod" changes the permissions of the real file, not the symlink.  Are you trying to change the permissions of the symlink?

Comment: @beepbeep That's not correct on a GNU/Linux system. `chmod` changes the permissions of the pointed-to file, not that of the symbolic link itself. Some versions of `chmod` have a `-h` option to achieve that, but anyway, permissions  of  symbolic links are never used. So, `find /var/www -type l -exec chmod 0775 {} \;` might be the easiest solution indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `awk` will probably fail if the link name has a space in it.

Instead of trying to fit it all in a pipeline, why not use a simple loop:

```
find /var/www -type l -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d link ; do
   rp=$(realpath "$link")
   chmod 775 "$rp"
done
```

If you absolutely must parse the output of `ls`, then

```
ls -lR | sed -n 's/^l.* -> //p' | sed 's/.*/"&"/'
```

would probably give you a better selection then your `grep`-`awk` pipeline